# CSS How to fit the bottom-border to a link with letter-spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a link where the text has some `letter-spacing`. Now the bottom border goes further than the link because of that. How can I avoid that e.g. how can I make the bottom border fit to the link text?

```
<a href="#">LINK</a>
```

css:

```
a { 
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   font-size: 30px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
   text-decoration: none
 }
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/90znr57h/2/)

Comment: No it doesn't..

Comment: @Rob use 100px, you'll see it. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/90znr57h/4/

Comment: @WesleyMurch I still don't.

Comment: @Rob he's talking about the normal behavior ;) he don't like that normal space after the last letter

Comment: @TemaniAfif He's talking about the border under the text, not after the text.

Comment: @Rob yes i mean the border under the last letter that is under the space after the last letter

Comment: I do not see the issue whatsoever.

Comment: @Rob i agree with you because it's not an issue :) this is the normal behavior of letter spacing but he doesn't like it. He want the border to end exactly under the last letter and don't consider the space added by letter spacing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok. NOW I understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to overcome this issue is to hack your way through it: by wrapping your text in a `span` we can remove 3px on the right with a negative `margin`:

```css
a {
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>LINK</span></a>
```

Comment: Put your markup within your question, not a jsfiddle. Links go dead and your answer will be useless to anyone in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: `this issue` : it's not an issue

Comment: @Rob, my markup is within my answer, in a snippet, but thanks.

Comment: You have an "updated fiddle". Is that the same as the snippet and example markup?

Comment: @Rob, my snippet and fiddle share the exact same code.

Comment: Then there is no need for the jsfiddle link.

Comment: @Rob Sure, there, it's edited. Good day.